# md5sum issue when calling service from Python

Tags: python, ros-melodic

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I have a problem when I try to call a Trigger service from Python. There is a service call `/ur_hardware_interface/dashboard/program_state` of the **Universal Robots Driver**, I can successfully call the service using the terminal `rosservice call /ur_hardware_interface/dashboard/program_state`. However when I try to call the service using a simply Python script, it fails

```
import rospy
from std_srvs.srv import Trigger, TriggerRequest

rospy.wait_for_service('/ur_hardware_interface/dashboard/program_state')
check_connection = rospy.ServiceProxy('/ur_hardware_interface/dashboard/program_state', Trigger)

req = TriggerRequest()
res = check_connection(req)
print("Check connection", res)
```

I get the following error message:

> rospy.service.ServiceException: unable to connect to service: remote error reported: client wants service /ur_hardware_interface/dashboard/program_state to have md5sum 937c9679a518e3a18d831e57125ea522, but it has 522d35a6f2ebd9702cb1e33489e1aa96. Dropping connection.

The universal robot driver is compiled from source in my catkin_ws, it is up-to-date, and has no modifications. The service and the client are running on the same PC so I don't really understand, though just in case I rebuild my catkin_ws but it does not change anything. Additionally, other services published by the **Universal Robots Driver** do work without problem from the Python script

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/374365/md5sum-issue-when-calling-service-from-python/) by [cambel07](https://answers.ros.org/users/50158/cambel07/) on ROS Answers with karma: 92 on 2021-03-20

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

As you can see in the documentation ([here](https://github.com/UniversalRobots/Universal_Robots_ROS_Driver/blob/16292b167108f33cfa93797bcb35c699431766ee/ur_robot_driver/doc/ROS_INTERFACE.md#dashboardprogram_state-ur_dashboard_msgsgetprogramstate)), the `dashboard/program_state` service is not of type `std_srvs/Trigger`, but type [ur_dashboard_msgs/GetProgramState](https://github.com/UniversalRobots/Universal_Robots_ROS_Driver/blob/98e0d87234cdbd75736c0a30b817cd4ec34bc469/ur_dashboard_msgs/srv/GetProgramState.srv).

You cannot call that service with a `std_srvs/TriggerRequest`, and the MD5 mismatch error is correct.

You can verify this by running `rosservice type /ur_hardware_interface/dashboard/program_state` (or `rosservice info ...` for more information).

Many services offered by that node actually use types other than `Trigger`, see again [the documentation](https://github.com/UniversalRobots/Universal_Robots_ROS_Driver/blob/16292b167108f33cfa93797bcb35c699431766ee/ur_robot_driver/doc/ROS_INTERFACE.md#advertised-services).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2021-03-20

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [cambel07](https://answers.ros.org/users/50158/cambel07/) on 2021-03-20**:
I see, thank you!